# Chrome iOS numbering link

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ipad

If link has number (like `<a href="link.html"> 20000 </a>`) in chrome ipad opens pop-up menu and try to call on this number. I added `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` but it didn't work, menu still shows and I can't go to page

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag to your header.  If you want other links to be phone numbers, use the "tel:" prefix.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: added but ipad still try to call

Comment: Try putting one or a couple zero-width joiners in the number.  `&zwj;`.